# How to make API calls with server side rendering in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have server side rendering up and running but am having trouble figuring out how to include data from an external API in my renders. Here are my core files.

**server.js**

```
import express from 'express'
import React from 'react'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import template from './template'  // the html template
import App from './client'

const server = express()

server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const context = {}
  const appString = renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
      <App/>
    </StaticRouter>
  );

  res.send(template({
    body: appString,
    title: 'SSR',
  }));
});

const port = 8080;
server.listen(port);
console.log(Listening on port ${port})
```

**client.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import Home from './containers/Home'

const App = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
  </Switch>
)

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  render(
    <BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
  )
}

export default App
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from './Layout'

import someAction from '../actions/SomeAction'  // this action calls an external api

export default class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            data: null
        }
    }

    // Somehow use "someAction" to hydrate this.state.data so the render
    // can return data from an external api

    render() {
            return (
                <Layout>
                    {this.state.data}
                </Layout>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The code is meant for just a simple outline of how I got server side rendering working with React. My question is how do I use an action that calls an external api and include the returned data in the component `render()`. I'm thinking this is the only way for `server.js` to `renderToString()` the complete html.